# Cache plugin for medium traffic news blog

Tags: plugins, cache

I have a middle-low traffic blog. Server is lite speed based. And ping values 20-25 MS for my Country ( this blog not global,just for my Country )

I want to Install a light cache plugin...

Which cache plugin can you suggest for me?

Thanks and sorry my bad English,good days.

Answer (score 1):

There is several of Cacheing plugins and tweaking available for WordPress.

Some plugins that i recommend for cache is:

[Wp Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) and 
[Quick Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-cache/)

**Description of Wp Super Cache:**

> This plugin generates static html files from your dynamic WordPress
>   blog. After a html file is generated your webserver will serve that
>   file instead of processing the comparatively heavier and more
>   expensive WordPress PHP scripts.

**Description of Quick Cache:**

> If you care about the speed of your site, Quick Cache is one of those
>   plugins that you absolutely MUST have installed. Quick Cache takes a
>   real-time snapshot ( building a cache ) of every Page, Post, Category,
>   Link, etc. These snapshots are then stored ( cached ) intuitively, so
>   they can be referenced later, in order to save all of that processing
>   time that has been dragging your site down and costing you money.

The both doing kinda the same stuff by generating static html and compressing it to the minimal. You can also use a image compressor like [wp-Smush-it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smushit/) by Yahoo that optimize all of your images.

You can also use a [Css,js and html compressor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) that minify your code to be as small as posible.

And if you want even more tweaking-stuff you could use [W3-total-cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) witch have a bunch of settings available.

Settings like:

- All of the above features
- CDN ( Content Delivery Network )
- Caching of database objects in memory or on disk
- Minification of html,css and js

Comment: Hi,thanks for answer :) But, When I install minifiy plugin or W3 total cache,my theme is broken and showing " ??????? " my blog...I will install WP Super cache,I think will be good...

Comment: And, can you suggest me a database optimizer plugin? Thanks :)